# What is difference between 'npm install' and 'npm rebuild'?

Tags: node.js, npm

I upgrade my node version from v7.1.0 to v9.4.0. After this m trying to run my server then I get this.

```
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 51. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 59. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
```

then I know about `npm rebuild`. I run both command `npm rebuild` and `npm install`. It fixed after run  `npm rebuild` but I do not understand what it does.
Please explain about `npm rebuild`

thank you

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**npm install**: It is obvious that `npm install` is used to install packages using the `package.json` file, this command also installs the other packages on which the packages (in `package.json`) are dependent.
On the backside, this command uses the `npm build` which helps to build the packages you are installing.

**npm rebuild**: As the name rebuild, this command again builds the packages, used only when you upgrade the node version and must recompile all your C++ addons with the new binary.

Comment: Do note, however, that `npm install` succeeds if optional dependencies fail to build, but `npm rebuild` stops after the first failure.  Leaving the rest of the packages not being rebuilt. One example of such optional dependency would be `ripe@0.2.1` that ultimately depends on `utf-8-validate@1.2.2`. The latter fails to build on my machine. But nevertheless that's an optional dependency, so `npm i` succeeds.

Comment: Also, if you happen to migrate to `npm-5.x` with `package-lock.json` being present, most likely `npm rebuild` won't suffice. `package-lock.json` was not respected, so you've got to not only rebuild the binaries, but also make sure that the packages are installed according to `package-lock.json`. `npm rebuild` just rebuilds what's installed. `npm i` can handle the latter. On the other hand, if a package version doesn't change, you've still got to rebuild it. So, you might need both.